# i tired round(7.285,-2) in SQL. What is the significance of '-' sign?

Tags: mysql, sql

round(7.285,-2) gave the output as 7.0
Can anyone pls explain how the output got generated?

```
round(7.285,-2);
```

output: 7.0

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Comment: If it's positive, it means digits after the decimal point. If it's negative, it means digits before the decimal point.

Comment: I get `0` for that, not `7.0`

Answer (score 0):

why are you using -2
just use `round(7.285)`
you will get 7.0 as output
by using -2 it will check up to 2 digits before the decimal
suppose u have a value 117.285
bu using -2 you will get 100.0
and by using +2 in 7.285
you will get output 7.29